# does fsockopen only allow certain servers?

Tags: php, ping

So I recently got round to contacting Hostgator about a previous Plugin I started which returns "Online" or "Offline" depending on the server status.

Now, here is the issue.

Hostgator had fsockopen disabled and after harassing them I had it Enabled. But not all server ips and ports work with it?

for example:

```
<?php
$ip = "play.magicacraft.net";
$port = "25567";

$online = @fsockopen( $ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 200);
if($online >= 200) { 
echo '<a href="#" class="MPServer_Online">Online</a>'; 
}
else {
echo '<a href="#" class="MPServer_Offline">Offline</a>'; 
} 
?>
```

That for me returns as online.

If i use another server ip and port such as:

```
$port = 72.20.55.85";
$ip = "25570";
```

It says offline ever though it's online

Is this a fault on my end or theirs? I question this because sites such as http://minecraftservers.org/index/1 can access this information and I can't.

Thanks for your time

Comment: fsockopen doesn't care about the ip. It sounds like the server can't access the address. Probably a firewall issue.

Comment: In the second example you misplaced the values of $port and $ip... Is this your error or is this just a typo in your question? :)

Comment: @ Jonathon, I'm confused. It's checking minecraft server IPs to see if they are online so it requires the port and IP

@ Sinni That was a typo on my end :P sorry

Comment: Did you check to make sure that port is not block by a firewall/iptables? Try the default example using port 80 http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php to see if it could be a port block issue

Comment: Hey R.S,

I had another chat with HostGator and found they have to infact unblock each Port... which I have to say is ridiculous.

Thanks for your help everyone. I found the code to work on Localhost

Comment: @Bradly Do you want me to add my previous comment as an answer, so we can close it and prevent other user from spending time on this?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind that would be fab!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check to make sure that port is not block by a firewall/iptables?

Try the default example using port 80 http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php to see if it could be a port block issue

Comment: Sorry I left this so late R.S, I just found it. Thanks for the post